# How to circumvent unused out parameters values?

Tags: c#, parameters, null, void, out

I am using `ConcurrentDictionary`, and I need to remove elements using `TryRemove`.

The implementation of `TryRemove` requires an out parameter that returns the object that will be removed.

```
Body dummy;
if (!bulletBodies.TryRemove(bullet, out dummy))
{

}
...
```

I do not want to use an additional line on a dummy variable whenever I delete an entry in my dictionary: that's why I tried to circumvent the out return parameter unsuccesfully typing the horrors below. I also googled a bit, without success.

```
bulletBodies.TryRemove(bullet, null);
bulletBodies.TryRemove(bullet, out null);
bulletBodies.TryRemove(bullet, void);
...
```

Is there a way or a clever tip to manage unused out parameters, so there is no need to declare dummy variables anywhere?

Comment: You could just create an extension method.

Comment: Extension method looks nice. However, is there really nothing specific to C# about handling unused out parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write an extension method, such as:

```
public static bool TryRemove<TKey, TValue>(this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    TValue dummy;
    return dictionary.TryRemove(key, out dummy);
}
```

Comment: Accepted for the code, and to balance amount of rep between two good answers.

Answer (score 7):

You can create an extension method TryRemove that does not return removed value.